# Fetching data from the Server

Tags: angularjs

I would like to fetch data from the server using a factory and then return an object which contains that data:

My data is located in the following folder data/es/20130709.json relative to index.html.

The data (20130709.json) is in the following format:

```
{
   "data": [
           {"price": 1593.00, "volume": 385},
           {"price": 1593.00, "volume": 385},
           {"price": 1593.00, "volume": 385}
           ]
}
```

What would be the best method to fetch this data and have the factory function return an object which contains this data.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried show the creation of the service, injection of $http and use of $http.get("data/es/20130709.json").success(function(data){}).error(function(data){});

Comment: Yes I tried the above.  I was getting an error.

Comment: In that case you should post the error you're getting, also use a non-minified AngularJS so it can be debugged, finally a plunkr or jsfiddle will help to see your error and show you a solution.

Comment: I think it might be an error within the json file.  I'll post back with a plunker if it still doesn't work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem I threw one together here too to show a "working" example, doesn't find the data file but nothing else seems to be breaking: http://jsfiddle.net/5HayJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module("myModule", []).service("myService", function($http){
    var service = {   data:[],
                      getData:function(){
                          $http.get("data/es/20130709.json").success(function(returnedData){service.data = returnedData});
                      }
                  };
    service.getData(); //calling to populate data as soon as possible

    return service;
}).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, myService){
    $scope.scopeData = {};
    $scope.$watch( function () { return myService.data; }, function ( data ) {
      // handle it here. e.g.:
      $scope.scopeData = data;
    });
});
```

The HTML

```
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>
</body>
```

And a fiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/5HayJ/

Comment: Thanks shaun.  I had a missing comma within the json file.  Your solution also works.

Comment: Ah yup, no problem, I have a tendency to make a lot of javascript syntax errors still too, glad you found it.